# Can't execute a specific SPARQL query on DBPedia :/

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

On [this site](http://www.kdedevelopers.org/node/3402), for example, take the first SPARQL query and make something very similar:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?name p:name <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Olivier_Theyskens> .
}
```

Try to execute it: [here](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20rdf%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20p%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%2a%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?name%20p%3aname%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Olivier_Theyskens%3E%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

And I get no results. However, modify the query to the following:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?name p:name ?otherthing.
}
```

And I get results, even though they're not the results I want.

Why doesn't the first query work -- what am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I think it's because you're ordering your query statement backwards.

The DBpedia resource (**`<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Olivier_Theyskens>`**) is the *Entity* or *Subject* (**`?s`**), the property (**`p:name`**) is the *Attribute* or *Predicate* (**`?p`**), and the value of that property (**`?name`**) is the Value or Object (**`?o`**).

SPARQL expects all statements to be **`{ ?s ?p ?o }`**, but yours seems to be written as **`{ ?o ?p ?s }`**...

To sum up, if you try this query --

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE 
  {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Olivier_Theyskens>  p:name  ?name  .
  }
```

-- you'll get [the results I think you want](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20p:%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Olivier_Theyskens%3E%20p:name%20?name%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=).

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your first query is that `p:name` links to Literal and you try to match a URI.

If you want your first query to work you have to to use the property `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/artist` that links to the URI and not the literal:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/artist> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Velvet_Underground> .
}
```

Notice the different name space for the property `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/artist>` this namespace contains `ontology` instead of `property` - `ontology` is the one used for object properties.

Comment: I see... That's quite troublesome, because this link I get from a different database, which only returns "http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Velvet_Underground". That's the only information I get from that database. So basically there's no solution to my problem?

Comment: Sorry I just completed reedited the question you have to use a different predicate <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/artist>